# I want to seek a set whose Hausdorff dimension is 1 and whose Hausdorff measure is infinity

Tags: real-analysis

I want to seek a compact set in $\mathbb R^4$ whose Hausdorff dimension is $1$ and whose $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is infinity. Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb R^1 $?

Comment: E is a subset in R^4

Comment: $\{\langle 0,0,t,0\rangle\mid t\in\mathbb R\}$, then.

Comment: Dear Henning Makholm, I want to find a compact set. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Lots of goalpost moving here, methinks.

Answer (score 3):

In comments you disclose you want a compact subset of $\mathbb R^4$. In that case, something like this should do:

$$ \{0\}\times\{0\}\times[0,1]\times\Bigl(\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N_+\}\cup\{0\}\Bigr) $$

Comment: Dear Henning Makholm, I think this set is bounded but not closed. Do you think so?

Comment: @user246529: It looks closed to me. Can you suggest a limit point that is not in it?

Comment: But I think a countable union of closed sets is not closed.

Comment: @user246529: There are countable unions of closed sets that are not closed. This one happens to be, however.

Comment: could you give me some clue to prove it?

Comment: @user246529: Can you prove that $\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N_+\}\cup\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: maybe I can thanks o lot.

Comment: Can you give me another example to find a compact set in R^4 whose hausdorff dimension is 1 but 1-hausdorff measure is 0

Comment: @user246529: It might be possible to do that with an appropriately tuned generalized Cantor set, but I don't have the details.

Comment: Could you tell me how to verify that the hausdorff measure of your set is infinite? Thanks .